# Exponential Distribution with possible Binomial Probability

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, exponential-distribution

You have a system with 6 components. In order for the system to work the following must be met:

Component 1 must work.

At least one of components 2, 3, 4 must work.

At least one of components 5, 6 must work.

Component 1 has an exponentially distributed mean lifetime of 1/2 a year.

Components 2,3,4 have an exponentially distributed mean lifetime of 1 year.

Components 5,6 have an exponentially distributed mean lifetime of 3/2 years.

All components function independently.

What is the probability that the system will function for at least 2 years?

So this is my thinking:

For each group of components, I find the probability that they will last less than 2 years using the cdf of exponential distribution. Then I subtract that probability from 1 to get the probability that they will last at least 2 years.  If we define $p_i$ as the probability that the $i^{th}$ component will last 2 years, we have:
\begin{align*}
p_1 = \exp(-2\times 2) &= 0.018\\
p_2 = p_3 = p_4 = \exp(-1 \times 2) &= 0.135\\
p_5 = p_6 = \exp\{-2/3 \times 2\} &= 0.263.
\end{align*}
Then, using binomial probability, I find the probability that all of the components will break. Then, I subtract that from 1 to find the probability that at least one of the components will not break.
\begin{align*}
1 - b(0;3,0.135) &= 1-(1-0.135)^3 &= 0.354\\
1 - b(0;2,0.263) &= 1-(1-0.263)^2 &= 0.458
\end{align*}
Finally, I multiply the 3 probabilities for the 3 different groups together to find my final answer.
$$
(0.018)\times(0.354)\times(0.458) = 0.00296
$$
So am I right?

Comment: I had written it as a percent, but thank you for verifying.

Comment: OK, my idiosyncrasy: I dislike percents in probability statements...

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so, please add the self-study tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% correct, assuming that all of the components lifetimes are independent.  I edited and added a little notation, partially so I can use it here.  If I may give a couple suggestions.

- Use more notation when you post here, because then people don't have to "back into" what value you are trying to calculate.  Especially when you (correctly) are frequently flipping between a value and its complement.
- In this case there was no need to use a binomial distribution.  If the components within any of the groups had different survival probabilities, then you *couldn't* use the binomoal.  Whereas, if you just said, the probability that the second group of components all fail, by independence is:

$$
(1-p_2) \cdot (1-p_3) \cdot (1-p_4).
$$

- Make sure you're aware of the assumptions you're making.  You used independence, many times, and if you were not aware of that, it will come back to bite you.

Comment: "All components function independently." & yes, I know of the alternate method to compute this. In fact, my reason for posting this was that I was getting different answers on both methods. I later realized that I had input 1 - b(0; 3, 0.263) instead of 1 - b(0, 2, 0.263) in Cran R... I just realized nobody caught on to that here. I'll edit that now as well. Edit: nevermind, I just noticed that you saw that. Thanks, I'm still new to this website

Comment: I had edited that, but it was awaiting peer review.

Comment: @picokol And thank you for pointing out the independence line.  I was looking for it before but couldn't find it.  It is important to know that using the binomial you are implicitly invoking that assumption.